# How to install onto a non-bootable pc

Tags: installation

I have an old Windows computer that won't boot (missing NTLDR or something??).  I don't even remember what Windows OS was on it.  Anyway, what I want to do is this: forget Windows and install ubuntu on this computer and then possibly sell it as a fully functional machine.  Can I download ubuntu onto a set of cd's or dvd's, using this Vista pc, then take the downloaded media to the broken machine and install ubuntu system from them?  Will the downloaded system on the cd's be bootable?  I have an old Win98 startup diskette that will boot to drive A: and that will let me change to drive D: (the cd drive).  So if the downloaded ubuntu system on cd's or dvd's is bootable, can I proceed to install it from there?

Comment: What do you mean by non-bootable?  If the BIOS doesn't load/past POST/etc. than the answer is probably no.  If you just mean that it doesn't boot into Windows, get yourself some Ubuntu installation media, change the boot order in the BIOS and you are good to go.  Definitely no need for a Win98 startup disk at any point....

Comment: can you be more specific about your computer spec. and there is not such thing like "non-bootable pc" seems like your machine is just old, and missing NTLDR (as you have mentioned)

Answer (score 5):

"missing NTLDR" is a *Windows* error message (NTLDR is the small program that boots Windows NT). If your computer makes it to that error message, then it is booting properly and has no issues, it is just the windows install that's broken.

So, the computer is *not* "non-bootable". Depending on how old is "old", it may be unable to boot the installation media directly, in which case you can just use a floppy loaded with something like [SmartBootManager](http://sourceforge.net/projects/btmgr/), which is able to boot CDs itself (no matter whether the BIOS supports bootable CD's or not, SBM has its own implementation of [El Torito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/El_Torito_%28CD-ROM_standard%29) (the bootable CD standard)).

You can use SBM if you have a floppy drive. I'm afraid the Windows 98 floppy won't be of much help here (there is probably some clever way to boot a live CD from MS-DOS, but it won't be as easy as just trying SBM).

Comment: Also,after you download the Ubuntu ISO, make sure that when you burn it to a CD, use a burning software that is capable of making a bootable ISO. In Windows Nero, Roxio, and DeepBurner are examples of capable programs. Windows CD writer is not.

Answer (score 2):

First thing to do is check if your hardware can handle Ubuntu.  For a list of system requirements [Click Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation)  and read the part that talks about requirements.  But I can tell you from past experience that it will be fine to install Ubuntu.

1) Get Ubuntu [Click Here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)

2) Burn The .ISO file that you downloaded into a CD.

3) Turn on the computer in question on.

3) Place the CD it in CD Drive of the the computer that you want to install Ubuntu on.

4) Go into the BIOS, and change the boot order to boot from CD.

5) Save and exit BIOS.

6) Ubuntu installation will start once the CD boots.

For more detailed or step-by-step instructions [Click Here](http://screamable.com/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-complete-step-by-step-guide.html)